# Suppressing ipdb output in Spyder iPython interpreter

Tags: debugging, spyder

I have reason to believe that my iPython interpreter is causing my kernel to die and restart similar to the issues logged in [this](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/4421) link and [that](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/4498) link.

The latter link indicates that the error is caused by the fact that the debugger outputs step-by-step `ipdb` content into the interpreter. One user reported that the behavior stopped when he (and I quote)

> disabled logging to console before running in debug mode

How does one "disable logging to console" in Spyder IDE/IPython? I really need to do this so I can at least step through my code....

**EDIT**

I would like to suppress this kind of output

```
ipdb> > d:\temp\other const models\plaxis\output\plotparfile.py(16)PlotParFile()
     14     with open(filename,'r') as fid:
     15         lines = fid.readlines()
---> 16     fid.close()
     17     #split first line get header and pop it out
     18     header = lines[0].split()

> d:\temp\other const models\plaxis\output\plotparfile.py(18)PlotParFile()
     16     fid.close()
     17     #split first line get header and pop it out
---> 18     header = lines[0].split()
     19     lines.pop(0)
     20
```

Comment: It's correct that this is a bug in Spyder. To avoid it you need to remove from your code any instruction that is printing something to the console.

Comment: None of my intructions are printing anything in the console. I am referring to this kind of output (see edit to original question). This is automatic output from the ipdb debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*Spyder developer here*) That output is generated automatically and its purpose is to tell you where are you placed in your code while debugging.

Right now there are no options in Spyder to deactivate it. Besides, I really doubt that output could be the cause of any kernel failures.

Comment: Ok thats all well and good. But I would like to find a stable version which can debug using the IDE. I tried downgrading like you indicated in the second link using `conda install spyder=3.1.3` in the anaconda prompt. This downgraded my version of spyder but then I got new errors that I wasn't getting in 3.1.4. For example 1) "cannot import name quick_guide" and 2)  the variable explorer is not synchronized with Ipython IDE and 3) IPython freezing. This makes me think that Spyder 3.1.3 is even less stable than Spyder 3.1.4. What do you suggest to be able to debug using the IDE?

Comment: All bugs you mention will be fixed in Spyder **3.2**, to be released in two or three weeks. We were aware of them since several months ago but we had to put a lot of work to fix them, as can be seen [here](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/pull/4202). So my suggestion is for you to wait until that version is released. Sorry for the inconveniences this causes you until then.

Comment: We're hard at work to release it on June 15, or at most June 25.

Comment: Hi @CarlosCordoba! Thanks a lot for all the work you guys are doing! Please consider adding the possibility to suppress the ipdb output in the future release. To keep track of which line is being debugged, we could just watch at which line in the code is highlighted.
Thanks :)

Comment: We're working on creating a better debugger for our next version.