# Python/Spyder: Is there a way to suppress the position output during debugging?

Tags: python, debugging, spyder

During debugging, everytime I step, I get a chunk of text telling me where I am, I am wondering whether there is a way to suppress this output, since I know where I am, the output is unnecessary and clusters the display, and hinders debugging.

I'm using python 3 on Spyder 3.2.8.

[image: debugging output example]

Comment: I would rather use ipython for debugging.

Comment: right now there is no way i can find (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44308115/suppressing-ipdb-output-in-spyder-ipython-interpreter) so i made a feature request on sypder github issue tracker
(https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/7787)